# Appending scripts to head using javascript - weird behavior

Tags: javascript, append, head, appendchild

The problem I'm trying to solve is an ad loading script, that loads the ad code with jsonp and inserts it into the dom.

Now sometimes the ad code will include javascript tags, and i figured it was just a matter of moving them to the head section and they would run. In theory that works fine but when i made a script to move script tags to the head i ran into some weird behavior.

So I wrote this code to test just the script moving part, eliminating the rest of the code as an error source.

I get the same results, if I have just two scripts in the div it moves one of them, if I have 3 scripts it moves 2 of them. In the code pasted below it moves script 1 and 3, skipping the remote javascript reference and the last script-tag.

Would be interesting to at least know why this happens, and if it can be solved.

Edit: To clarify one thing, if i put the remote jquery script first and one of the simple script tags second it will move the remote script tag to the head fine and skip the second script tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
// get div id
function test() {
var td = document.getElementById('testId');
var scripts = td.getElementsByTagName("script");
console.log("No. of scripts to transfer to head: "+scripts.length);
for(i=0;i<scripts.length;i++) {
    var curScript = scripts[i];
    document.head.appendChild(curScript);
}   
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="test();">
<div id="testId">
    <script type="text/javascript">var firstScript = 1;</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">var secondScript = 1;</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">var thirdScript = 1;</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're laboring under a false assumption: It doesn't matter whatsoever whether `script` elements are in the `head` or `body`, they get run regardless. Moving them after they've been appended to the DOM is at best pointless, and at worst may cause unfortunate side-effects if the script is re-run when moved (but I don't think it is).

As for why you're seeing the behavior you're seeing, it's because [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094) returns a **live** [`NodeList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-536297177). When you move a script, it gets removed from the `NodeList`. So given your four scripts, you'll get back a `NodeList` initially containing four elements, so `.length` is `4` and `[0]` is your first script. When you move that script out of the `div`, the `NodeList` is updated because the script is no longer in the `div`, so its length is now `3` and `[0]` refers to your second script (the one loading jQuery).

You can avoid having this behavior interrupt your loop in two ways:

1. Loop backward, from `.length - 1` to `0` inclusive, or
2. Turn the `NodeList` into an array, so the elements aren't moved out from under you.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, but the javascript inserted into the DOM does not run when it is inserted into the div or when it is moved to the head.

Comment: @user: If you insert an actual `script` element into the DOM, the script it contains is run immediately. If you're not seeing that behavior, I'd recommend a separate question (since this one is more about why the loop was ending early) showing what you're doing and asking why you're not getting the result you expect. Best,

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on setting up an example for a new question now.