# Dojo dialog dynamic content

Tags: javascript, dojo

I would like to ask you, how can I dynamicaly create HTML content with using javascript. It means, that I need create simply dojo dialog and than I "tell him" with another js file, which content it can show. 
Or I have html file, which contains some calling on javascript functions, but it doesnt work. Static tags are showed, but js doesnt render content. It is possible with dojo something like this, because I didnt find something.

Miro

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy in dojo to create a dialog and give it some content from javascript on a page. The easiest method I have found so far is to create the dialog in dojo-flavored javascript, then create content in it's `containerNode` using `dojo.create`.

```
dojo.require('dijit.Dialog');

function showDialog() {
  var dialog = new dijit.Dialog({ title: 'Confirmation' });
  dojo.create('div', {
    innerHTML: 'Are you sure you want to do this?'
  }, dialog.containerNode /* the content portion of the dialog you're creating */);
  var div = dojo.create('div', {}, dialog.containerNode);
  dojo.create('a', {
    href: '#',
    innerHTML: 'Yes',
    onClick: function() {
      /* do yes stuff */
    }
  }, div);
  dojo.create('a', {
    href: '#',
    innerHTML: 'No',
    onClick: function() {
      /* do no stuff */
      dialog.hide();
      dojo.destroy(dialog);
    }
  }, div);

  dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank for your quick reply. And I have one more question, is it possible make sometihing like
**var xxx = doCreateHTML(a,b,c)** where "doCreateHTML(a,b,c)" is javascript function where I dynamic create some part of HTML code based on aruments, and than I use **innerHTML: xxx** from your code? Or how can I create this one case?

Comment: It is certainly possible, but without more information I cannot help you out. You need to flesh that comment out a bit more with your requirements and add a new SO question. I'm not sure if a comment is going to get you your answer.

Comment: My problem is, that I have one html file with html tags and <script>doCerateHTML(a,b,c)</script> tags. When I put it to dojo dialog as a content, those <script> tags are ignore and content contain only html tags. So I try to find a way, how to "tell" to dojo dialog to create content from this javascript function. I cannot be more concrete, becouse Im at home and this code I have in work.

Comment: script tags in innerHTML will not get executed automatically. 
see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789502/running-script-tags-fetched-with-jsonp for some clues on how to proceed. You can probably also look into using dojo.parser.parse() on the specific element but that may be an overkill